# read a huge 90 mb file from a URL

Tags: java, json

How to read a large json file line by line from a URL . My json file have to be read from a url through http . once i read the url ,open the url stream and i have to read line by line . its a json format file . Please help.
i have tried to read from the url as below:

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
String line, results = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
results += line;
        }
reader.close();
is.close();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(results);
JSONArray fileArray = json.getJSONArray("Documents");
```

then iam looping the Array again for each line.Any suggestions to improve the code here.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is the file just one large json object?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using here?  Most libraries have some sort of streaming API you could use if you know the general format of the JSON you're expecting.

Comment: what do you want to do with file? is it something that you want to load at once or how? line by line? showing it to the user?

Comment: `results += line;` on a 90MB file is going to hurt... You could start by using a StringBuilder instead of a String.

Comment: i have one json array named Documents . Then inside this array i have multiple lines where each line has objects Action and Filenames(pointing to other files location which are html format). basically i want to read this json file line by line and work on this action and filename seperately.Because action and filenames are different in each line.

Comment: There seems to be problem in the code.it consumes lot of memory and also takes a long time to process each files.

Comment: Have you tried using other tools like from [apache commons - IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) `IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://apache.org"), "UTF-8");`?

Comment: Yes i tried this IOUtils.tostring .  I did the same and passed the string to JSONObject.This is how you are saying?

Comment: It should be faster then way you are doing it now  since `results += line` will really slow your app and `IOUtils` will solve this problem by using its own StringBuilder.

Comment: Ok i will try this . shall i store some string to IOUtils.toString(url) and pass that string to JSONObject?

Comment: What i see is fetching the url of JSON file itself touches around 1 GB of memory and it takes a long time to read this big file.

Comment: @user3161879 I am not sure what you are asking. Also add `@pshemo` at start of your comment if you are writing massage to me. This way I will get note about your massage. I read your previous comment only because I didn't close this page yet.

Comment: @Pshemo iam sorry for that . What iam trying to tell is i wrote this line of code now : String jsonText = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url), "UTF-8");
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);                              but i see its consumed close to 1 GB so far and not finsihed to fetch the URL still. My concern is why does it take so much time and also memory.

Comment: I am not sure myself. I would expect copping arrays to bigger ones in case buffer could not handle current data but this should end when you get right size and if GC didn't delete previous arrays used by buffer it would still be max 2x of memory taken but current size of buffer. Do you see this memory consumption while file is downloading or while JSON is parsing it?

Comment: @Pshemo iam seeing this memory consumption by just downloading the file over the network. Before even the string is passed to JSONObject.Leaving the memory also ,iam assuming to read a 90mb file over network should not taken more than 30 minutes right. I mean its still running for long.

Comment: I am not sure why is it happening. Try maybe with `new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new URL("http://jakarta.apache.org").openStream()), "utf-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next()` instead and tell if you get similar problem.

Comment: @Pshemo how do i pass this to jsonObject?

Comment: The same way like previous. It should return String object.

Comment: @user3161879 Well, I don't use JSONObject often so I definitely am not an expert. Maybe it is using recursion somewhere to analyse structure of document. Maybe it doesn't have enough memory to effectively parse this string after downloading it (you mentioned that downloading took 1GB of your memory). It is hard to guess without actually seeing your document. I think you should create separate question for this so other users may explain it better.

Comment: @user3161879 No problem. I am also here to learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments on the question:

> i have one json array named Documents . Then inside this array i have multiple lines where each line has objects Action and Filenames(pointing to other files location which are html format). basically i want to read this json file line by line and work on this action and filename seperately.Because action and filenames are different in each line.

I gather that the format you're working with is something like this:

```
{"Documents":[
  {"Action":"action 1", "Filenames":["file 1a", "file 1b"]},
  {"Action":"action 2", "Filenames":["file 2a", "file 2b"]},
  // and so on for thousands more array entries
]}
```

Rather than try and load the whole top-level JSON Object in one go, it would make more sense to use some sort of streaming API and process one "row" at a time.  For example, using [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you could do something like this with the [`JsonReader`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) API:

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(r);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

reader.beginObject(); // the initial '{'
String name = reader.nextName();
assert "Documents".equals(name);
reader.beginArray(); // the opening '[' of the Documents array
while(reader.hasNext()) {
  JsonObject doc = parser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
  String action = doc.get("Action").getAsString();
  JsonArray filenames = doc.getAsJsonArray("Filenames");
  // do something with the document here
  // ...
}

reader.endArray(); // ending ']' of Documents
reader.endObject(); // final '}'
reader.close();
```

This way you only have to hold one "row" in memory at a time.

There are similar APIs in other JSON libraries, though some are more fiddly than others (for example with the json.org `JSONTokener` you have to handle the `:` and `,` separators yourself explicitly).

Comment: @an Roberts is there anyway to get the size of array Document completely. Just wanted to know how many lines r processed. For monitoring purposes.

Comment: @user3161879 not up front, you'd have to count them yourself by declaring a counter variable that you increment each time round the `while` loop.

Comment: @an Roberts ok thanks . Your Program was very helpful.

Comment: @an Roberts :the code was running sucessfully for long and it ended up with some exception saying com.google.gson.JsonIOException: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF

Comment: @user3161879 the stack trace and the error message should give you some indication of exactly where the error is. Are you sure that the JSON file is indeed well formed? Remember the code I gave is just an example, you may need to tweak it to fit the format of the real data, JsonReader has a skipValue method you can use to skip over bits you're not interested in.

Comment: No the premature EOF is random.. At times it comes for some lines and at times it doesnt come for same line while processing. Not able to understand why it is occuring only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to read JSON from a URL:

```
public static String readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException
{
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      return jsonText;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
    return "";
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You're not likely to improve the performance by tweaking this code, at the end of the day you're still transferring a 90mb file over the network.

Comment: I was getting out of memory and also now it didnt improve the code either. So any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You get an out of memory error using this code? I could see your original code running out of memory but the code I posted shouldn't. Is the URL you're reading from public?